# Is there a way to open .stl files in android without using already made software like STL viewers?

Tags: android

I am making an  android app to encrypt and decrypt `.stl` files in android. Only link that I found vaguely relevant is  https://github.com/kshoji/STLViewer. I am looking for more recent implementation. I am new to STL and this has very less resources.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).